# How to define function that uses class type as a parameter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I simply try to do the following:

```
func popTo(classType: AnyClass, from context: UINavigationController?) {
    let controller = context?.viewControllers.first { $0 is classType }
    context?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

I need to use it like this:

```
popTo(SettingsViewController.self, from: navigationController)
```

Comment: Unrelated but why is `context` optional (the code doesn't compile even if the `classType` issue has been fixed)? And isn't it *swiftier* to extend `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 3):

As far as the compiler is concerned, `classType` isn't a type like `String` or `Int`. It's just the name of a parameter (which stores a type). But the `is` operator expects a type (that can be resolved at compile time) on its RHS.

We need a type that is known at compile time. We can pass such a type parameter with generics:

```
func popTo<T>(classType: T.Type, from context: UINavigationController?) {
    if let controller = context?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is T }) {
        context?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

You can also add the constraint `T: AnyObject` to more closely reflect the `AnyClass` (= `AnyObject.Type`) in your original code, but you don't particularly have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
func popTo<T: UIViewController>(classType: T.Type, from context: UINavigationController?) {
    let controller = context?.viewControllers.first { $0 is T }
    context?.popToViewController(controller!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The context is similar to the first answer. While posting this answer I didn't receive the first answer, when I posted and reload the page I got it. so it's the same context as the first answer. BTW I will sure take care of this.